# How do you implement XOR using +-*/?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, xor

How can the XOR operation (on two 32 bit ints) be implemented using only basic arithmetic operations? Do you have to do it bitwise after dividing by each power of 2 in turn, or is there a shortcut? I don't care about execution speed so much as about the simplest, shortest code.

**Edit:**
This is not homework, but a riddle posed on a [hacker.org](http://www.hacker.org). The point is to implement XOR on a stack-based virtual machine with very limited operations (similar to the [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) language and yes - no shift or mod). Using that VM is the difficult part, though of course made easier by an algorithm that is short and simple.

While FryGuy's solution is clever, I'll have to go with my original ideal (similar to litb's solution) because comparisons are difficult to use as well in that environment.

Comment: do you mind shifting and the modulus operator too?

Comment: x << a === x * (1<<a)
x >> a === x / (1<<a)

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.  I've always considered it a best practice to cite any external references, but it would be pretty brazen to cite your own question on stackoverflow.  What an ethical dilemma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry i only know the straight forward one in head:

```
uint32_t mod_op(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint32_t int_div = a / b;
    return a - (b * int_div);
}

uint32_t xor_op(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint32_t n = 1u;
    uint32_t result = 0u;
    while(a != 0 || b != 0) {
        // or just: result += n * mod_op(a - b, 2);
        if(mod_op(a, 2) != mod_op(b, 2)) {
            result += n;
        }
        a /= 2;
        b /= 2;
        n *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The alternative in comments can be used instead of the if to avoid branching. But then again, the solution isn't exactly fast either and it makes it look stranger :)

Comment: you have to revert the bits of result at the end.

Comment: i tested it at codepad.org and works :) i would have to revert if i would do result *= 2; but instead i use the n to add the 1bits to result. so i don't have to revert at the end

Comment: yeah, I tested it too and it runs fine, my bad =)

Comment: I came up with the same solution. +1

Comment: another way is to check for "mod_op(a - b, 2) != 0", but it depends on "underflow" behavior of the programming language, so i better don't put it in :)

Answer (score 17):

I would do it the simple way:

```
uint xor(uint a, uint b):    

uint ret = 0;
uint fact = 0x80000000;
while (fact > 0)
{
    if ((a >= fact || b >= fact) && (a < fact || b < fact))
        ret += fact;

    if (a >= fact)
        a -= fact;
    if (b >= fact)
        b -= fact;

    fact /= 2;
}
return ret;
```

There might be an easier way, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Voting up, this seems the simplest implementation.

Comment: i like this one too. hands down, as much as i love my straight forward way, but you deserve a vote up :)

Answer (score 11):

I don't know whether this defeats the point of your question, but you can implement XOR with AND, OR, and NOT, like this:

```
uint xor(uint a, uint b) {
   return (a | b) & ~(a & b);
}
```

In english, that's "a or b, but not a and b", which maps precisely to the definition of XOR.

Of course, I'm not sticking strictly to your stipulation of using only the arithmetic operators, but at least this a simple, easy-to-understand reimplementation.

Comment: Down voted, huh? Twice? Although my answer applies to a slightly different scenario than the one defined by the OP, I think it still provides helpful ancillary information.

Comment: I was about to ask the question that this answers - so you get an upvote from me at least. =)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you have the AND because

A OR B = A + B - (A AND B)

A XOR B = A + B - 2(A AND B)

```
int customxor(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b - 2*(a & b);
}
```