# GLSL - Why are bitwise operators reserved? What is a good alternative to using bitwise ops (floating point ops that emulate bitwise)

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl, webgl

I'm running some experiments in WebGL, one of them being an XOR effect fragment shader. For some reason all the bitwise operators are reserved in GLSL and cause a compiler error when used. Why are these operators illegal? What can I use instead of | in this case?

Comment: You mentioned an XOR effect, but then you said "instead of `|`" (the bitwise OR operator). Did you mean "instead of `^`"?

Comment: Well, I was going after the first effect this this post - http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/623 The author called it the 'XOR' effect, so monkey see monkey do. Its name might have more to do with the look of the effect than the code to affect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the GLSL 1.0 spec, they were reserved "for future use", which was the 1.3 spec. It's allowed for unsigned and signed integers, both scalar and vector.

You should begin your shader by

```
#version 130
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess version 1.3 is not supported on Chromium's webgl, as I'm getting the error 'Version number not supported by ESSL'

Comment: Most of the time, you can workaround xor with if() : i=0; if(cond1) i++; if(cond2) i++; if (i==1)....

Comment: for logical XOR, yes... but the question was for *bitwise* XOR; how do you workaround that?

Comment: I guess you're pretty much stuck. The only solution that comes to mind is to precompute everything in an integer texture, and access it. Very limited of course. BTW, make sure you drivers are up to date, one never knows.

Comment: Note that integer support and bitwise operators are _not the same thing_. Bitwise operators are a `EXT_GPU_shader4` feature (core OpenGL 3.2), and require `#version 1.50` (or higher) in GLSL.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too, e.g. trying to run Slisesix in [Shader Toy](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/) using Chrome.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373262/how-do-you-implement-xor-using) has two answers showing ways you could implement bitwise XOR without bitwise operators. They might be slow, but in some cases they'd be fast enough. Better than nothing.

You might also see whether `+` is a close enough approximation to bitwise XOR, depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could pick this answer too.