# How can one implement | and & (bitor,bitand) using +-*/%?

Tags: language-agnostic

How to implement bitOR and bitAND operation (on two variable-sized ints, but at least as small as 8 bits)  using just basic arithmetics? I don't care about execution speed, the most important is the simplicity and size of code. I've managed to get negation, xor and shifts implemented.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373262/how-do-you-implement-xor-using?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have xor, then I propose the following:

```
bitAnd(a,b) = ((a+b) - bitXor(a,b)) / 2
```

where / 2 is (truncated) integer quotient of division by 2 (or bit shift 1 place to the right).

Beware, integers must be sufficiently wide to not overflow!
If we loose highest bit in `(a+b)` operation, then the operation will not work.

Then you can reconstruct bitOr with one of:

```
bitOr(a,b) = bitXor(a,b) + bitAnd(a,b)
bitOr(a,b) = (a+b) - bitAnd(a,b)
```